# Why is it correct to say "I am having a party tomorrow" but not correct to say "I am having class tomorrow"?

Tags: grammar

Why is it correct use *have* in the present continuous tense when talking about parties but incorrect when talking about class. For example:

> I am having a party tomorrow.
>
> I have class tomorrow.

but not

> I am having class tomorrow”?

Comment: A teacher might easily tell someone that s/he **is having a class tomorrow**, meaning **giving a class tomorrow** or **receiving tuition tomorrow.. A pupil is more likely to say **I have class tomorrow**, meaning attending a regular class tomorrow.  Both are possible.

Comment: You (a student) are definitely not "having a class tomorrow".   That's incorrect use.  `have a class`, and `have class` (informal), are in use, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `having` with events to indicate that you are organizing, arranging, or otherwise causing an event to be expected to occur on a definite timeframe.

> I am having a party.
>
> I am having a family dinner.
>
> I am having a meeting at my home.

but not

> I am having a doctor's appointment.
>
> I am having a birthday.
>
> I am having a potential visit by my mother in-law.

In the first three, you could replace `having` with `holding` or `organizing`.  In the last three, you could not.

Comment: Let's say I am s teacher and I am giving clases tomorrow. Do I say "I am having class" or "I am having classes tomorrow"?

Comment: You likely wouldn't, because classes are almost always on a fixed schedule; you didn't decide or arrange specifically to have a class tomorrow, most likely.  If the situation was such that it was the teacher's discretion when are when not to hold class, it suddenly sounds natural again for her to tell her students "We are having class tomorrow", however.

Answer (score 2):

The way to say you have a class would be:

> I have a class tomorrow.

You *could* say the same about a party:

> I have a party tomorrow.

However, this means that you are *attending* a party.

"I am *having* a party" is an idiomatic way to say that you are *hosting* a party.